# Respository and Identity in asp.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

The `User` property (type `IPrincipal`) of a controller comes from the base `Controller` class. I would like to use a repository to keep as much of my code as possible out of my controller, and also aid testing. Since my repository doesn't inherit from `Controller`, how can I get the `User` information in my repository methods without passing it in?

Comment: So what have you tried? Code would be nice

Comment: IPrincipal is in the BCL, you can pass a concrete implementation of it between projects.

Comment: Implantation is not an issue, it's the actual current user from the http context I'm looking to get access to in the repository, to avoid passing in a reference from the calling controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this

```
    private IPrincipal CurrentUser
    {
        get
        {
            return HttpContext.Current.User;
        }
    }
```

and all is well.